# Yowsup auth fail whatsapp

Tags: python, api, whatsapp, yowsup

i am working on an api for whatsapp, i am using Yowsup.
when i use Yowsup Cli client i manage to login to the whatsapp account and send and receive messages from it.
when i try to use the following script, it return "Auth Failed!".

```
import sys
import os
import logging
import time
import shutil
import Queue
from collections import defaultdict

from Yowsup.Common.debugger import Debugger
from Yowsup.connectionmanager import YowsupConnectionManager

from py_utils import logutils
from py_utils import executable_utils
from py_utils import exception_utils

from py_utils.cli_utils import actions_handler


COUNTRY_CODE = "COUNTRY_NUM"
PHONE_NUMBER = "MYNUMBER"
# IDENTITY = ""
PASSWORD = 'MY_PASS_WORD'
LOGIN = COUNTRY_CODE + PHONE_NUMBER

import argparse, sys, os, csv
from Yowsup.Common.utilities import Utilities
from Yowsup.Common.debugger import Debugger
from Yowsup.Common.constants import Constants
from Yowsup.Contacts.contacts import WAContactsSyncRequest
from Yowsup.connectionmanager import YowsupConnectionManager

import threading,time, base64

########## DO NOT COMMIT THIS FILE WITH YOUR CREDENTIALS ###########
#.....................WhatsApp Account Config.......................

nickname = "lamaaaaaaa"
username = LOGIN
password = PASSWORD

id = "" # Not required

#....................................................................

# Degug is False by default if you add -d you will set it to True
Debugger.enabled = True if '-d' in sys.argv else False
password = base64.b64decode(bytes(password.encode('utf-8')))

def login(username, password):
    print "[] Logging in as %s (%s)\n" % (nickname, username)
    methodsInterface.call("auth_login", (username, password))

def onAuthSuccess(username):
    print("Authed!!\n\n")
    methodsInterface.call("ready")
    methodsInterface.call("presence_sendAvailableForChat", (nickname,))

def onAuthFailed(username, err):
    print("Auth Failed!")

########################### BIND EVENTS #############################
connectionManager = YowsupConnectionManager()
signalsInterface = connectionManager.getSignalsInterface()
methodsInterface = connectionManager.getMethodsInterface()
connectionManager.setAutoPong(True)

signalsInterface.registerListener("auth_success", onAuthSuccess)
signalsInterface.registerListener("auth_fail", onAuthFailed)
#####################################################################

login(username, password)
```

Comment: from Yowsup.Common.debugger import Debugger and 
from Yowsup.connectionmanager import YowsupConnectionManager  are raising error when I am executing ? any help ? I guess, This has to do something with the path ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the the access token need to be update.
in the Yowsup package there under comon \ constans.py 
there a need to update the tokanData to :

```
tokenData = {
    "v": "2.12.53",
    "r": "S40-2.12.53",
    "u": "WhatsApp/2.12.53 S40Version/14.26 Device/Nokia302",
    "t": "PdA2DJyKoUrwLw1Bg6EIhzh502dF9noR9uFCllGk1416435341393{phone}",
    "d": "Nokia302"

    # "v": "2.12.15",
    # "r": "S40-2.12.15",
    # "u": "WhatsApp/2.12.15 S40Version/14.26 Device/Nokia302",
    # "t": "PdA2DJyKoUrwLw1Bg6EIhzh502dF9noR9uFCllGk1391039105258{phone}",
    # "d": "Nokia302"
}
```

you can see the difference between what i had and what i need to use

Comment: I am getting this error: from Yowsup.connectionmanager import YowsupConnectionManager

Comment: post a question with some info and add the link and i will try to help